# Quarkus Reactive Messaging doesn't start separate thread using JMS connector and SmallRye implementation

Tags: multithreading, jms, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye

In my scenario the application reads messages from a JMS queue by using a CDI-Producer.

```
@Produces
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JmsFactoryFactory ff;
    JmsConnectionFactory factory;
    try {
      // Get a new JMSConnectionFactory
      ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
      factory = ...
```

I'm using the quarkus-smallrye implementation.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
      <artifactId>smallrye-reactive-messaging-jms</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The connector looks quite simple:

```
  @Incoming("ORDER")
  public CompletionStage<Void> consume(Message<String> message) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processMessage(message)).thenRun(message::ack);
    // used a Runnable, ...
  }
```

The configuration:

```
mp.messaging.incoming."ORDER".connector=smallrye-jms
```

I tried different approaches to handle messages, but in every case, I got only one worker thread.

The logs shows every time the same result:

```
 [DEBUG]          Thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15,5,main]
 [DEBUG]          Thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15,5,main]
 [DEBUG]          Thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15,5,main]
 [DEBUG]          Thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15,5,main]
 [DEBUG]          Thread Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15,5,main]
...
```

I used this [documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/2.7/index.html) and searched a lot ;-)

What's my mistake?
Why do I get only one thread running?
If you need further information, let me know.

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? Does the queue have enough messages to actually trigger the creation of multiple consumer threads?

Comment: I am using an IBM MQ queue and fill in 15 messages, which currently are consumed sequentially.

Comment: Are you using ["Read Ahead"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032570_.htm)? This is a very common performance optimization for message consumers. The downside of this kind of optimization comes when there are a relatively small number of messages as the messages can get concentrated on a single or a few consumers. I suspect this may be happening in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried to set the read-ahead flag in the connection factory.

`factory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_READ_AHEAD_ALLOWED, WMQConstants.WMQ_READ_AHEAD_ALLOWED_ENABLED);`

But in the log of quarkus only one thread is active:

`... WorkflowManager] (pool-11-thread-1) ...`

If I add an additional annotation to the Consumer class:

`  @Metered
  @Incoming("ORDER")
  @Outgoing("RESULT")
  @Blocking(ordered = false)
...
` 
the internal thread pool is used, but the requests are processed sequentially by different thread.

Comment: @MarkHunt can you post your `pom.xml` and the way you setup the `ConnectionFactory` ? I'm also trying to setup smallrye-reactive-jms, but I'm getting errors (The channel 'mychannel' is configured with an unknown connector (smallrye-jms)).